# can't get element by onclick selector method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I couldn't get a onclick tag with selenium webdriver.

```
<a class="TopIcon MwIcon MwExcel" 
href="#" onclick="mw.ExportWindow()" 
onmouseover="ShowTooltip(this)" 
onmouseout="HideTooltip()" 
desc="خروجی, ساخت فایل از اطلاعات معاملات"></a>
```

So the element inspect are the above codes.
There is no id tag or something else.
So I already tried this in python :

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a[onlick*=mw.ExportWindow()]')
```

But I get the error : invalid selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct css.

```
a[onclick="mw.ExportWindow()"]
```

There is a typo in your css `onclick` and you have to wrap the attribute value in single/double quotes.

```
a[onclick*='mw.ExportWindow()']
```

Comment: `browser.find_element_by_css_selector(a[onclick*='mw.ExportWindow()'])`
I did it. but I get this error : 
invalid syntax

Comment: It should be `browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick*='mw.ExportWindow()']")`